# Get attribute from multiple WMS sources

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms, json

I'm using GeoServer and I need to put the value of NDVI from four different wms into a chart. I'm using also OpenLayer for my map.

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
  var viewResolution = view.getResolution();

  var ndvi_array = [], ndvi_20200706, ...

  var url_20200706 = sourceNDVI_20200706.getFeatureInfoUrl(
    evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
    {
      'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
      'propertyName': 'GRAY_INDEX',
    });
  console.log(url_20200706);
    fetch(url_20200706)
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.text(); })
      .then(function (data) {
  
        var json = JSON.parse(data).features[0];
  
        var ndvi_20200706 = json.properties.GRAY_INDEX;
  
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error)
      });
  console.log("NDVI 6 luglio 2020: "+ndvi_20200706);
  ndvi_array.push(ndvi_20200706);
  
   var url_20190706 = sourceNDVI_20190706.getFeatureInfoUrl(
    evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
    {
      'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
      'propertyName': 'GRAY_INDEX',
    });
  console.log(url_20190706);
    fetch(url_20190706)
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.text(); })
      .then(function (data) {
  
        var json = JSON.parse(data).features[0];
  
        var ndvi_20190706 = json.properties.GRAY_INDEX;
  
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error)
      });
  
.
.
.

console.log("Array: "+ndvi_array);

});
```

I'm be able to see on the map all wms.

**EDIT 1**

Probably my question isn't clear and I've edit the code with all my purpouse.
What I want to do is put the NDVI index of all WMS into an array because I need to use an array for a chart.

**EDIT 2(after @Mike indications)**

I've edited all code, now in console log I see this when I click on a point:

> NDVI 6 luglio 2020: undefined
> Array:

Comment: What is in the response from the server if you look in the developer tools of the browser? most likely error is you forgot to set CORS support

Comment: Inside developer tools I see this error when I click on a point: `Uncaught TypeError: url_20200706.features is undefined`. Where I must set the CORS support?

Comment: @Ian Turton you cannot get a CORS error without a network request.  `url_20200706` is a url string, it does not have a features property, the url needs to be fetched.

Comment: See the example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-image.html  After calling `getFeatureInfoUrl` you must fetch the url to obtain the data

Comment: @mike I know that I can use fetch, I've edit my question with my complete code, I don't have a strong Javascript skills.

Comment: Fetch is an asynchronous operation.  You will need to declare your variables at the start `var ndvi_array = [], ndvi_2020, ndvi_2019;` and set the values in the fetch response `ndvi_2020 = json.properties.GRAY_INDEX; ndvi_array.push(ndvi_2020);` If you need to handle all the responses together you will need to use javascript `Promise.all` logic.

Comment: @Mike I've edited my code with your indications. Probably is better if you give me an answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the data callback is asynchronous and won't run until after the console.log.  Also you have redeclared `ndvi_20200706` by using `var` in the callback

You could simply set a timeout and hope all your results are in after 5 seconds

```
  var viewResolution = view.getResolution();

  var ndvi_array = [], ndvi_20200706, ...

  var url_20200706 = sourceNDVI_20200706.getFeatureInfoUrl(
    evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
    {
      'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
      'propertyName': 'GRAY_INDEX',
    });
  console.log(url_20200706);
    fetch(url_20200706)
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.text(); })
      .then(function (data) {
  
        var json = JSON.parse(data).features[0];
  
        ndvi_20200706 = json.properties.GRAY_INDEX;
        ndvi_array.push(ndvi_20200706);
  
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error)
      });

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("NDVI 6 luglio 2020: "+ndvi_20200706);
  console.log("ndvi_array: "+ndvi_array);
}, 5000);
```

But it would be better to wait for all the fetches to complete and handle the results together, something like

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
  var viewResolution = view.getResolution();

  var fetches = [];
  var url_20200706 = sourceNDVI_20200706.getFeatureInfoUrl(
    evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
    {
      'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
      'propertyName': 'GRAY_INDEX',
    });
  fetches.push(fetch(url_20200706)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.text(); }));

  var url_20190706 = sourceNDVI_20190706.getFeatureInfoUrl(
    evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
    {
      'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
      'propertyName': 'GRAY_INDEX',
    });
  fetches.push(fetch(url_20200706)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.text(); }));

  Promise.all(fetches).then(function(results) {
    var ndvi_array = [];
    results.forEach(function (data) {
      var json = JSON.parse(data).features[0];
      var ndvi_20200706 = json.properties.GRAY_INDEX;
      ndvi_array.push(ndvi_20200706);
    });
    console.log("ndvi_array: "+ndvi_array);

    // continue your processing here

  });
});
```

For more info including error handling see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all